# Quotation mark converted into code in string

Tags: json, string, ejs

I have a use case where an object was passed from server to client through EJS like below:

```
res.render('mytemplate', {data: myobject});

<script type='text/javascript'>
        <% if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data) { %>
          data: '<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>',
        <% } %>
</script>
```

I'm having this issue that in the client code, the returned stringified object looks like

```
{&#34;key&#34;:&#34;value&#34;}
```

whereas it is supposed to be

```
{"key":"value"}
```

So when I do JSON.parse() in the client code I get an error. How do I keep the quotation marks in the string instead of the special character code? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, this is unrelated to typescript or express, I suggest you to change the title & tags. Up to you though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will change the title & tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the `unescaped` way in your template:

```js
data: '<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>',
```

Note the `<%-` instead of `<%=`

See the documentation "Tags" section: https://ejs.co/#docs